# multiple types webapi parameters binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

is it possible to have an api endpoint whose method's sign can accepts a parameter that can be a single object or a collection of objects?

i have a method like this:

```
[HttpPost, Route("DoSomething")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] MyType xxx, CancellationToken cancel)
```

i need to modify this method to accept a collection of MyType class (an array, enumerable, list... doesn't matter)

```
[HttpPost, Route("DoSomething")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody] IEnumerable<MyType> xxx, CancellationToken cancel)
```

anyway for a little while the client that calls this endpoint will continue to send me a single object `{ }` and not a collection of objects `[{ },{ }]`

is it possible to modify this endpoint to accept both types?

Comment: Is this .NET Framework or .NET Core? In other words, is it using JSON.Net or System.Text.Json?

Comment: @DavidG .NET full framework Newtonsoft.json

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom `JsonConverter`. For example, this should work, or at least be enough for you to customise:

```
public class SingleOrListConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(List<T>);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }

        return new List<T>
        {
            token.ToObject<T>()
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you add it to your configuration. In `Global.asax.cs`, add this line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters
    .Add(new SingleOrListConverter<string>());
```

Now just use a single endpoint:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoSomething(
    [FromBody] IEnumerable<MyType> xxx, CancellationToken cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 solutions:

1. Accepet the data as `string`, and you can parse it yourself in any way, you can process the string, give it different rules to judge which type it should be convert, e.g. if contains `[` then parse it as List, otherwise a single object.
2. Write 2 methods one accept List another Single Obj, and write usage clearly in api documentation, then provide the document to the user.

Comment: Writing two methods like those i wrote above i get this error '404 bad request  "Message": "Multiple actions were found that match the request"'

Comment: try give the method different name, so the url route will be different